# Using AR.JS in a html element other than body

Tags: javascript, angular, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am trying to use ar.js with angular, but ar.js seems to always apply itself to the body element and so destroys the page. Is it possible to declare some element like canvas to be the output element for the ar video?
My question seems to be related to https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/209 this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ar.js` appends the canvas to the `body` element by itself, so you could make an embedded website and put it in an `<i-frame src="myScene.html>`

Working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/embedded-ar).